# Override save in Django causing infinite recursion error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

(Django 2.0, Python 3.6, Django Rest Framework 3.8)

I'm trying to override Django's `save()` method to post multiple instances when a single instance is created. I have a loop that changes the `unique_id` which I have saved as a randomly generated string, and the datetime value which is updated through another function called `onDay()`.

My thinking was, that if I changed the `unique_id` each time I looped around, Django would save the instance as a new instance in the database. But, I keep getting back an infinite recursion error when I run it though. When I checked it with `pdb.set_trace()`, everything does what it's supposed to until I hit the `save()` value in the for loop. Once that happens, I just get taken back to the line `if self.recurrent_type == "WEEKLY":`.

I've used `super()` in a similar way (without looping) to override the `save()` function for a separate model, and it worked as expected. I think there's just something I'm misunderstanding about the `super()` function.

Here is what I have so far:

**Overriding save()**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # if there is not yet a pk for it
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            if self.recurrent_type == "WEEKLY":
                LIST_OF_DAYS = self.days_if_recurring["days"]
                HOW_MANY_DAYS_FOR_ONE_WEEK = len(LIST_OF_DAYS)
                REPEATS = HOW_MANY_DAYS_FOR_ONE_WEEK * self.number_of_times_recurring
                RESET_COUNTER = 0
                for i in range(REPEATS):
                    self.id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=30))
                    self.calendarydays = onDay(self.calendarydays, LIST_OF_DAYS[RESET_COUNTER])
                    if RESET_COUNTER == HOW_MANY_DAYS_FOR_ONE_WEEK - 1:
                        RESET_COUNTER = 0
                    self.save()
            else:
                self.id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=30))
                self.save()
        return super(Bookings, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**onDay()**

```
def onDay(date, day):  # this function finds next day of week, and skips ahead one week if today's time has already passed
    utc = pytz.UTC
    check_right_now = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
    if check_right_now > date:
        forward_day = date + datetime.timedelta(days=(day - date.weekday() + 7) % 7) + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    else:
        forward_day = date + datetime.timedelta(days=(day - date.weekday() + 7) % 7)
    return forward_day
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You write `self.save()` in the `if self.recurrent_type == "WEEKLY"` in the `.save()` function, hence you call the function in its definition. Since the `self.recurrent_type` is never changed (nor other parameters that determine the loop), this can indeed result in infinite recursion.

Comment: I see, thanks for the input @WillemVanOnsem , do you happen to know what I'm able to do to fix this? I'm at a complete loss

Comment: Try to remove `self.save()`, you have that in `if self.recurrent_type == "WEEKLY"` and its `else`.

Comment: You should call `super(Bookings, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` instead of `self.save()`. The super save will call django's actual model save which is what you want. Calling `self.save()` will just call your overridden save which doesn't do anything in the database. But yeah what @AamirAdnan said should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody! I ended up using the solution provided by @bdbd (Can you please post your solution as an answer so I can accept it?). In addition to avoiding the infinite recursion, I made the mistakes of: (1) saving the variables as `self.id` when they should have been `self.unique_id` (2) I wasn't incrementing my counter variable `RESET_COUNTER` (3) I should have been returning `None` at the bottom to avoid double-saving duplicate `unique_id`s. All is working as expected now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `super(Bookings, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` instead of `self.save()`. The super save will call django's actual model save which is what you want. Calling `self.save()` will just call your overridden save which doesn't do anything in the database. But yeah what @AamirAdnan said should fix your problem.